# How can get the url of the page from where data form is posted to the current page (in php)?

Tags: php, url, post

I want to get the url from where data is posted to the current page. Suppose I captured a data in current page like-

```
$connect=$_POST['connect'];
```

and I want to be sure that data came from a specific url, not from any other else. So, I want to get the url of that page from where that data originally came from.
How can I do that by php ?

-Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your kind replies. I just now tried " $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] " but also found in this discussion and from http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php that it can't be trusted completely. So please tell me whats the better solution that can be completely trusted. -Thanks.

Comment: If I try to check the url of paypal on my 'notify_url' page by $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] then is that a bad idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. But be warned that it is not reliable, as the client can easily modify it or omit it completely (this is especially true if user is using a proxy).

Look here for details: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: So whats the way (to get referer url) that I can trust completely ?

Comment: Oh, thats bad. So please tell me if I use that to get data on notify_url page from paypal then would it be a bad idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You should get this by reading the referer

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

But watch out: The user simply can turn off submitting the referer.

Comment: If the user turns off the referer then is there any other trusted way to get the referer url ?

Comment: So if I use that to get data on notify_url page from paypal then would it be a bad idea ?

Comment: No, but I suggest to check, if the value is set before using it blindly. Thats a good advice for all user submitted data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now please tell me last thing, suppose I've 2 pages on my server and I want to submit user form from a page to another securely. So in this case how can I make sure that the submitted form data came from the specific page and all data are being unchanged ?

Comment: You can never be completely sure, that user submitted data is not manipulated. So that's just impossible.

Comment: I see, so that will keep a headache there always. May be the 'https' is kinda better for that but not so sure though. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to access

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

That would do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

go through the documents..

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

According to the answers of **cem,Jan Hančič,Fredrik** and **bipen** .

Thank you all for your kind help. At the end I've got a conclusion that I can get the url of the page (from where the form data is posted to the current page) by using-

```
$url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

But this can't be trusted completely cause the 'http header' informations can be changed or hacked or the user may use proxy server (ref:-

> "But be warned that it is not reliable, as the client can easily modify
>   it or omit it completely (this is especially true if user is using a
>   proxy" 
>   -Jan Hančič

) or

> "But watch out: The user simply can turn off submitting the referer." 
>   -cem

. And I didn't find a way which can be trusted completely to get the url of a webpage from where data is posted. In this case 'https' can be used but don't know how secured is that really, so there always will be a headache for that.

Anybody's help to get the completely trusted way about that will be appreciated much as well as would be accepted for the answer.

-Thank you so much.